# Display text with if statement

Tags: android, eclipse

I have some if statements, I do not know how to show the result on the screen.
Below are 2 things I have tried. I know the system.out goes to the log.

```
if (Enter == "1") {
    // tv.setText("This is the display 1");
    System.out.println("The 1");
}   
else if (Enter == "2") {
    System.out.println("The 2");
}
```

Comment: Is `Enter` a `java.lang.String`? If so, you need to use `.equals()`.

Comment: I have used .equals, now I just need to replace the system.out

Answer (score 1):

What is `Enter`? If it is an instance of an object, use lowercase names, so that would be `enter`.

To answer the question, you're probably comparing `String`s. You should use `.equals` instead of `==`.

So:

```
String enter = "1"; //your variable
if(enter.equals("1")){
    System.out.println("The 1");
}else if(enter.equals("2"){
    System.out.println("The 2");
}
```

When comparing primitive data types (like `int`, `char`, `boolean`) you can use `==`, `!=`, etc.
When comparing objects (like `String`, `Car`, etc) you need to use the `.equals()` method.

[See also this page.](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html)

***Edit***

Use a Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "The 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

[See here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

Comment: I have used the proper form I just need it to display on screen now, so what should I replace the system.out part with?

Comment: I should replace the system.out.println with the toast for each if statement?

Comment: Or store the message in a `String` the way @matthew proposed

Comment: This is what I have for my if statement. with "PleaseEnter" I have first set it as a number when getting input from the user, then changed it to a string for the if statement.
if ("1".equals(PleaseEnter.getText().toString().trim())) {
//your stuffs
} else .....

Answer (score 0):

Do it with a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) instead.

A Toast is a popup-like element in Android displaying a short message for a predefined duration on screen.

```
String enter = "whatever value enter has";

int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
Context context = getApplicationContext();

String message = "The Nothing";
if (enter.equals("1")) {
    message = "The 1";
} else if (enter.equals("2")){
    message = "The 2";
}

Toast messageToast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
messageToast.show();
```

Comment: you can't use `==` to compare strings. Instead use `.equals`